# Difference in nuance between 証明 and 証拠?

Tags: nuances

I know that both of these words mean "proof", but I can't figure out what the difference is, or if there's any at all. Can anyone explain to me the difference in nuance between these two words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

証明 is used for conceptual proof, e.g. in the mathematical sense.

証拠 is substantial proof in the sense of evidence, like evidence used in court, e.g. as in the phrase

> 証拠で裏付けられる
>   to be backed by evidence

Answer (score 12):

Broadly speaking, 証明 is proof and 証拠 is evidence. That is to say, you provide evidence in order to prove something. Accordingly, 証明 is both a noun and a verb, but 証拠 is not a verb, or in other words you can 証明する, but you cannot 証拠する.

This [dictionary entry for 証明](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/110248/m0u/%E8%A8%BC%E6%98%8E/) makes the relationship pretty clear:

> １ ある物事や判断の真偽を、**証拠を挙げて明らかにすること**。「身の潔白を―する」「本人であることを―する書類」「身分―」「印鑑―」

Emphasis added. There are legal uses that follow the general English pattern, for example a judge will use *evidence*, documented evidence, to make a decision, to judge if that evidence sufficiently *proves* the claim.

As stated in the other answer, 証明 also refers to a mathematical proof (論証).